# How can I scroll text inside of a div using js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to scroll the content of the div which is some text, without any tags it's just like "some text"

I have set the height of the div to be 600px and overflow property as auto, so I all want is after some interval the content i.e the text should be scrolled to the next 600px of the div.

EDIT:

So, what I actually want is, when I paste some content in the div, it should scroll down after some interval

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div class="paper-content" id="note" contenteditable="true">

              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut rhoncus dui eget tortor feugiat iaculis. Morbi et dolor in felis viverra efficitur. Integer id laoreet arcu. Mauris turpis nibh, scelerisque sed tristique non, hendrerit in erat. Duis interdum nisl risus, ac ultrices ipsum auctor at. Aliquam faucibus iaculis metus sit amet tincidunt. Vestibulum cursus urna vel nunc imperdiet suscipit. Ut eu augue egestas, porta orci lobortis, pharetra orci. Morbi eu tellus quis nisi tempor accumsan nec eu urna.

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.paper-content{
height: 600px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
function scrollToBottom(){
  alert('here');
  document.getElementById('note').scrollTop = document.getElementById('note').scrollTop + 100;

}

// Convert copied text to plaintext
document.querySelector("#note").addEventListener('paste', (event) => {

  event.preventDefault();

  var text = event.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");

  document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text);

  setTimeout(scrollToBottom, 1000);

})
```

Like I have,

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj7CA.png)

then after some interval, it should be scrolled to,

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDZuq.png)

Thank you!

Comment: What is your problem then??? I think your question have answers!!!!!! Also, where are your codes.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Your question as currently written  shows no research effort.

Comment: Thank you @YuryTarabanko for the suggestion I have added codes so that you can reproduce.

Comment: @TusharPatil is your problem solved?

Comment: No, I followed your suggestion but no luck, I think when I paste the content, the cursor moves to the very last, but the the intial part is visible, is this causing some issue?

Answer (score 2):

Using scrollTop you can achieve what you want

```js
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('text-content').scrollTop = document.getElementById('text-content').scrollTop + 100;
}, 2000)
```

```css
#text-content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px soild;
    overflow: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div id="text-content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit  
</div>
```